# Subtract values in column from values in other column if value in other is not nan and > 0 else skip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here's an easy question

I have a two columns in a 800+ row dataframe

```
Col  Bias
 1    -1
 2     1
 3    -0.03 
 4     0.1
 5     nan
....   ....
```

I want to replace col with col-bias if the value in bias is greater than 0. If it's less than 0 or nan then I want to keep the original value

example output:

```
Col  
 1   
 1    
 3     
 3.9
 5
....
```

I tried doing with a mask

```
mask=data[(data["bias"]>0) | (data["bias"]!=np.nan)]
data.loc[mask,"Col"]=data.loc[mask,"Col"]-data.loc[mask,"Bias"]
```

But I get an error Cannot index with multidimensional key

I feel like I can do this with df["col"].apply(lambda x: ) but am confused what x would be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be as simple as:

```
df.loc[df.Bias>0, 'Col'] -= df.Bias
```

Output:

```
   Col  Bias
0  1.0 -1.00
1  1.0  1.00
2  3.0 -0.03
3  3.9  0.10
4  5.0   NaN
```